# How to reset JSESSIONID

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

It is considered a good security practice to reset the session cookie when a user authenticates.

How to do this with Java?

My attempt so far is successful, but I was wondering if there's a better way:

```
public static HttpSession resetSessionId(HttpSession session, 
      HttpServletRequest request) {
    session.invalidate();
    session = request.getSession(true);
    return session;
}
```

Comment: I think that is the best way...

Comment: I have tried your way. But the JSESSIONID didn't reset. Do you know know why? Im using Resin as my web container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer seems optimal. Another way would be to directly manipulate cookes in this fashion:

```
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("JSESSIONID", "randomValue");
 cookie.setMaxAge( 0 );
```

so you create a new cookie with the same name and immediately expire it, but I **don't recommend** going this way since yours is much cleaner and pretty obvious to anyone who's familiar with basic Servlet APIs.

Comment: I'll actually use this, because thus I'll be able to set the "secure" flag to false. Tomcat is setting it to `true`, because I'm authenticating via SSL

Comment: well, actually it didn't work - somehow it sent two identical JSESSIONIDs, rather than overriding the existing one. So I had to drop the entire resetting for now. But still preserving the accepted answer, as most complete.

Answer (score 4):

I only pass the request from which I get the session. If a session doesn't yet exist there is no point in creating one just to invalidate it. This also holds if the session has just been created by the container (due to the user first http request directly on the login form).

```
public static ... (HttpServletRequest request) { 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session!=null && !session.isNew()) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: well, a session should exist before authentication (I use a custom authentication, no built-in http auths). When the user opens the login page, a session is created.

Comment: I prefer to be very optimal regarding session creation in my webapps. An http session is explictly created by Java code only when required. Displaying a login form doesn't usually require any state handling.

Comment: @Bozho, what cherouvim says is very true, handling session prior to authentication (or any other state required) can be easily exploited for OOM DoS (just call the page creating the session but never store, i.e. executing exactly the same GET request). So I guess this is the best answer (alongside w/ the comment)

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat (since 6.0.24 AFAIK) can change the sessionId on authentication automatically - as long as you're using standard servlet authentication mechanisms (basic, form based authentication). This can be configured via changeSessionIdOnAuthentication for the Basic Authenticator Valve: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way (not the better way) is to call 'changeSessionId(existingSession)' of   `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager` which will change the session ID of the current session to a new randomly generated session ID.

You have to use StandardManager Mbean to invoke that method. Please see [Tomcat MBeans](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/funcspecs/mbean-names.html)

Pseudo code:

ObjectName contextObjectName = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,path=/whatever,host=whateverhost");

mbeanServer.invoke(contextObjectName, "changeSessionId", new Object[]{session}, new String[]{"javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"});